# OpenVPN configuration works standalone but not as daemon

Tags: openvpn, openwrt

The whole setup works standalone, ex: `openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/openvpn.conf`, remote can ping server, and server can ping  the remote

When I start the server with `--daemon`, the remote client can ping the server and the network behind the server, but the server cannot ping the remote.

Server: 10.20.0.1
Remote: 10.20.3.1
Intermediate network: 10.20.201.0/24

server's openvpn.conf:

```
mode server
tls-server

### network options
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun

### Certificate and key files
ca /etc/easy-rsa/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/easy-rsa/keys/server.crt
key /etc/easy-rsa/keys/server.key
dh /etc/easy-rsa/keys/dh1024.pem

server 10.20.201.0 255.255.255.0
#push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "route 10.20.0.0 255.255.255.0"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.20.0.12" # Change this to your router's LAN IP Address
client-to-client

client-config-dir ccd
route 10.20.3.0 255.255.255.0

ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

### (optional) compression (Can be slow)
#comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun

verb 3
keepalive 10 120
```

The host 10.20.3.1 is learned after the client connects and shows in logs, when not running as daemon.

Thanks!

[edit]

Both hosts are on OpenWRT on a TPLink WR-1043ND. Remote host is connected via internet.

[edit]

The "daemon" doesn't learn the route to 10.20.3.x, as it does when running it directly from the commandline

[edit]

OpenVPN 2.1.4 mips-openwrt-linux [SSL] [LZO2] [EPOLL] built on Nov 14 2011
Originally developed by James Yonan
Copyright (C) 2002-2010 OpenVPN Technologies, Inc.

[edit]

I built a vm with this version:

Mon Jul 16 16:49:58 2012 OpenVPN 2.2.1 x86_64-linux-gnu [SSL] [LZO2] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [eurephia] [MH] [PF_INET6] [IPv6 payload 20110424-2 (2.2RC2)] built on Mar 30 2012

same issue :S

Comment: I could use `nohup` but there's no build for my arhcitecture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

....

`client-config-dir` needed a full path